# WPF DataGridNumericUpDownColumn set value from DataTable

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to set the value the `DataGrid` Column "`DataGridNumericUpDownColumn`" from a Database. I get the data as `DataTable` and bind it to the `DataGrid`.

That's the table I fetch my items from.

```
CREATE TABLE Items
(
    ITEM varchar(64),
    PART_NUMBER varchar(64),
    TYPE varchar(64),
    MANUFACTURER varchar(64),
    PRICE decimal(32,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ITEM, PART_NUMBER, TYPE, MANUFACTURER),
    FOREIGN KEY (MANUFACTURER, TYPE)
    REFERENCES ManufacturerType(MANUFACTURER,TYPE)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

C# Code

```
private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // ITEMS TABLE                                                                          //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder();
    command.Append("SELECT MIN(ii.IMAGE_PATH) AS IMAGE_PATH, MAX(i.ITEM) AS ITEM, i.PART_NUMBER AS PART_NUMBER, ");
    command.Append("MAX(i.TYPE) AS TYPE, MAX(i.Manufacturer) AS MANUFACTURER, i.PRICE FROM ");
    command.Append("Items i ");
    command.Append("LEFT JOIN Item_Images ii ON i.PART_NUMBER = ii.PART_NUMBER ");
    command.Append("GROUP BY i.PART_NUMBER, i.ITEM");
    //SETUP COLUMNS FOR ITEMS TABLE
    DataTable dt = mysql_database.queryDataFromDatabaseWithSQLCommand(command.ToString());
    dgItems.Columns.Add(createImageColumn("IMAGE", new Binding("IMAGE_PATH"), new Size(32, 32)));
    foreach (DataColumn dcol in dt.Columns)
    {
        if (dcol.ColumnName.ToUpper() == "PRICE")
        { 
            dgItems.Columns.Add(createDataGridNumericUpDownColumn(dcol.ColumnName.ToUpper(), "C"));

        }
        else
        {
            DataGridTextColumn dgc = new DataGridTextColumn();
            dgc.Header = dcol.ColumnName.ToUpper();
            dgc.Binding = new Binding(dcol.ColumnName.ToUpper());
            dgc.IsReadOnly = true;
            dgItems.Columns.Add(dgc);
        }
    }
    dgItems.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

The code for creating the DataGridNumericUpDownColumn

```
public DataGridNumericUpDownColumn createDataGridNumericUpDownColumn(string header, string format)
{
    DataGridNumericUpDownColumn dtemp = new DataGridNumericUpDownColumn();
    dtemp.Minimum = 0.00;
    dtemp.Binding = new Binding("{" + header + "}");
    dtemp.StringFormat = format;
    dtemp.Header = header;

    return dtemp;
}
```

However when I run my application, the field with the `numericupdown` is empty.
The value will not be set from the DataTable.

The running tool:
[image: Image of the running tool]

This is what's stored in the database.

The data row in the database:
[image: Image of the data row in the database]

I'm out of ideas how to get this working. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: binding path shouldnt have { or }. make it `new Binding(header)`. general tip: look into Visual Studio Output window to find any messages about binding errors

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Removing the brackets did the job ;) Thank you!